# OpenOffice.org Calc SUMIF statement

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to sum all cells in C2:C2000 if the corresponding cell in column A is in (10; 20], but I'm having problems with the condition.

I've tried something like `=SUMIF(A2:A2000, AND(">10","<=20"), C2:C2000)`, but that returns 0 which is incorrect.

Thanks.

[edit]

It is possible to use `=SUMIF(A2:A2000, ">10", C2:C2000) - SUMIF(A2:A2000, ">20", C2:C2000)` but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have tried to accomplish what you hope to accomplish in MS Excel and am running into the same problem.  It seems that Excel and OpenOffice cannot evaluate compound logical statements like ' ">10" & "<=20" '.  What about writing a user function like BETWEEN() which takes three arguments and returns a TRUE or FALSE: the number to be compared, the lower bound, and the upper bound?

Comment: @Jubbles Thanks, I'll see if there is a way to write complex conditions and I'll post here if I find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to get around the complex conditions limitation is to use another column as a 'local variable' - make column D the result of your condition (AND(etc)), hide it if you want to have less screen clutter, and use D2:D2000 as the if part of the SUMIF.

edited to add alternate option:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275165

use Sum(if( .. )) instead of SUMIF, and use products and sums instead of ANDS and ORs.

Personally, I think using an intermediate column is easier to follow and maintain.

Comment: Possible, yes, but I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to use complex logical statements in SUMIF, COUNTIF, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A relatively elegant solution in OpenOffice is to use Sumproduct -- which multiplies together two arrays.  Feed Sumproduct with successive truth tests on the range (which return an array of booleans, I think).  Something like this:

```
SUMPRODUCT(C2:C2000;A2:A2000>"10";A2:A2000>="20")
```

I got this from here:

http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=28585

Tested in OpenOffice -- I have no idea if there's an equivalent in Excel.  Sorry, I don't have a copy to test on.